# Integrate Swift library in Objective c "Property not found on object of type" in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I am trying to make Mobile Number Registration screen which contains All country flags, Name, And Country detail codes so I am using [FlagPhoneNumber](https://github.com/chronotruck/FlagPhoneNumber) which is swift and also supports objective c.
But when I tried to use the properties like it give me compiler error of property not found on the object type

What I have Done

1. I created a .swift file which prompted for bridge-Header-file.h I've added that.
2. I have imported `//#import "FlagPhoneNumber-Swift.h"` for the class when I want to use the library.

Any suggestions would be more helpful or if can tell suggest some other libraries for the flags and dial code will also be great to me.

Comment: You are using it in swift or in Objective-C?

Comment: my project is in objective c

Comment: See the library you are using is developed for `swift` language. So you can use all the properties of that library in Objc. To use that properties you need to modify and assign them to `@objc`. But I would not recommended that, better you use similar ObjC library.

Answer (score 0):

Check the -Swift.h file which has the import on your .m file in objective-C:

```
#import <YourProjectName-Swift.h>
```

Click on that line, and left-click - Jump To Definition.

This file should be included automatically, not manually.
If you're still not seeing your class even after importing -Swift.h.

Make sure that your class is subclassing a native class (e.g UIViewController) or at least if it's just a utility class, make it subclass NSObject. Your class should now show.

Comment: In this there is class called `FPNTextField` i am able to access this but properties inside this class is what i  am getting trouble .